# JSF: How to invoke a method from object?

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

I have a bean. That bean returns an object:

```
public class LogoBrick {
    private String logoLink = "link";

    public LogoBrick() {
        System.out.println("LogoBrick");
    }
    public String getLogoLink() {
        return logoLink;
    }
    public void setLogoLink(String logoLink) {
        this.logoLink = logoLink;
    }
    public void save() {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS: " + logoLink);
    }
}
```

and I want to (in jfs file) invoke the method from this object:

```
<h:form id="logo-form">
    Logo link: <h:inputText id="logoLink" value="#{brick.logoLink}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{brick.save()}"/>
</h:form>
```

The method save and the setter is not invoked but the getter is.
Could anyone tell my why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your save method should return a string, i think.

Comment: @BheshGurung that's true for JSF 1.x. Since JSF 2, you can use a `void` method in order to not execute a navigation.

Comment: Please add your whole JSF page. With the actual code, it's hard to tell if you have another error that's causing this.

Comment: @BheshGurung Event I changed the return type of the method and the result  is the same. But I think I've found error. The tag <h:form id="logo-form"> was in <c:choose> bloc but when I removed it, the save method has started to work.